# Apache Kafka Neo4j Connector issues

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, apache-kafka-connect

I set up kafka neo4j sink connector the following way:

1. Created `/tmp/plugins`, downloaded `neo4j-kafka-connect-neo4j-5.0.3-kc-oss.zip` (for Apache Kafka) and unzip into plugins folder i.e.
2. Modified `connect-standalone.properties`, added `plugin.path=/tmp/plugins`
3. Created `connect-neo4j-sink.properties` in config with the following

   ````
   topics=my-events
   connector.class=streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector
   key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
   key.converter.schemas.enable=false
   value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
   errors.retry.timeout=-1
   errors.retry.delay.max.ms=1000
   errors.tolerance=all
   errors.log.enable=true
   errors.log.include.messages=true
   neo4j.server.uri=bolt://neo4j:7687
   neo4j.authentication.basic.username=neo4j
   neo4j.authentication.basic.password=neo4j
   neo4j.encryption.enabled=false
   neo4j.topic.cypher.my-topic=MERGE (p:Person{name: event.name, surname: event.surname}) MERGE (f:Family{name: event.surname}) MERGE (p)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(f)```
   ````

And when I start:

`/bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-neo4j-sink.properties`

I get this error:

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector`

**Environment**

- neo4j:5-community
- apache kafka 2.13-3.6.0

Comment: In the startup logs, Connect will print all plugins it did find. Use that to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried rebuilding the artifact and discovered my java version was outdated. Upgrading to java 11 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: do you think the documentation could be improved?

Comment: Most definitely. The documentation could definitely be improved with a compatibility matrix with this information